# Deployment fails on Google app engine

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, deployment, jpa

I have a java application (spring mvc, jpa) and i am trying to deploy it on google app engine.
For some reason I get the following error when deployment is done

........................
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.

Error Details:
Feb 26, 2011 10:43:58 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: \about.jsp
Feb 26, 2011 10:45:41 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: \faq.jsp
Feb 26, 2011 10:47:23 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: \footer.jsp
Feb 26, 2011 10:49:05 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: \synchronize.jsp

java.io.IOException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=subsconvertor&version=0.1&
500 Internal Server Error

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.

Please see the logs [C:\Users\CRISTI~1.POP\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg6738798550184437418.log] for further information.

And int he log I have:

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.

```
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ServerConnection.send(ServerConnection.java:149)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ServerConnection.post(ServerConnection.java:82)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:579)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.beginTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:397)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:112)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:56)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:547)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:138)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:61)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:57)
```

com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=subsconvertor&version=0.1&
500 Internal Server Error

Any idea what can be wrong?

Cheers,
Cristian

Answer (score 21):

It's possible that the '.' in your version number is mucking things up.

The version identifier can only contain "letters, digits, and hyphens" ([from google documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#About_appengine_web_xml)).

Comment: I'd say +2, but can only +1 :)