# Internal server error, uploading Google App Engine project as secondary owner

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have several GAE projects and have no problem uploading them. I am now working on a project with my brother. He added me as a co-owner of the project this evening. I then went to upload a new version of the project using my google account and got the following error...

```
Unable to update:
java.io.IOException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=mouse-master&version=1.1&
500 Internal Server Error

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.

    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:207)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:639)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.beginTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:446)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:137)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:300)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:52)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:598)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:65)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:61)
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=mouse-master&version=1.1&
500 Internal Server Error

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.

    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:305)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:52)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:598)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:65)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=mouse-master&version=1.1&
500 Internal Server Error

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.

    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:207)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:639)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.beginTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:446)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:137)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:300)
    ... 5 more
```

Has anyone successfully uploaded a Google App as a secondary owner of the project. My brother can upload the project using his Google account. But it would be nice for both of us to be able to do this. From what I read in the Google Apps documentation it should be possible. Do I have to wait XX hours after accepting my brothers co-ownership request until I have permission to upload?

Here is the output when I try to upload using the console

```
C:\Users\Dad\Documents\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.
5.2.r35v201107211953\appengine-java-sdk-1.5.2\bin>appcfg.cmd update c:\Users\Dad
\workspace\MouseMaze3\war
Reading application configuration data...
5/08/2011 11:53:32 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader r
eadAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed c:/Users/Dad/workspace/MouseMaze3/war\WEB-INF/appen
gine-web.xml
5/08/2011 11:53:32 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader
 readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed c:/Users/Dad/workspace/MouseMaze3/war\WEB-INF/web.x
ml
5/08/2011 11:53:32 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexesXmlReader readCo
nfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed c:\Users\Dad\workspace\MouseMaze3\war\WEB-INF\appen
gine-generated\datastore-indexes-auto.xml
Beginning server interaction for mouse-master...
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\Dad\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg34090768
50418058192.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.

java.io.IOException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appv
ersion/create?app_id=mouse-master&version=1.1&
500 Internal Server Error

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/app
version/create?app_id=mouse-master&version=1.1&
500 Internal Server Error

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.

Please see the logs [C:\Users\Dad\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg6558856430947435547.l
og] for further information.

C:\Users\Dad\Documents\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.
5.2.r35v201107211953\appengine-java-sdk-1.5.2\bin>
```

Comment: I don't have any problem doing that. I can update my application using both a normal account and a Google Apps account.

Comment: What's the root cause of the exception? It doesn't tell enough. If you abort an upload process you will need to do a cleanup before you can do another upload. Make sure that this is not the case with you.

Comment: You don't have a problem doing what? I can update the projects **I** created. However, I can not update the project my **brother** created, and added myself as a co-owner of.

Comment: How do I do a cleanup... I initially tried to upload the project before my brother added me as co-owner and I got a different error. After he added me I got the error above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer at [this stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126026/deployment-fails-on-google-app-engine)
The actual problem was that I had changed the version number to 1.1. The version numbers in Google Apps Engine can only contain letters, numbers and hyphens.